# POST in PHP data format error

Tags: php, json, post

I'm trying to POST using php. In the API it's suggested the following format.

```
// post url, keys are added here.

{
    "EmailAddress": "john.smith@acmeconsulting.co",
    "ActivityEvent": 112,
    "ActivityNote": "Note for the activity",
    "ActivityDateTime": "yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss",
    "FirstName": "John",
    "LastName" : "Smith",
    "Phone" : "+919845098450",
    "Score": 10
}
```

My code in PHP :

```
$firstName='Test5';
$activityEvent=201;
$emailAddress='test10@test.com';
$activityNote='Note note note';
$phone='999999999';
$date='2015-07-21 12:48:10';

$data_string['ActivityEvent']=$activityEvent;
$data_string['EmailAddress']=$emailAddress;
$data_string['ActivityNote']=$activityNote;
$data_string['Phone']=$phone;
$data_string['ActivityDateTime']=$date;
//json_encode($data_string);
 try
{
  $curl = curl_init($url);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
                      'Content-Type:application/json',
                      'Content-Length:'.strlen($data_string)
                      ));
 $json_response = curl_exec($curl);
 curl_close($curl);
 } catch (Exception $ex) {
 curl_close($curl);
}
```

This code is not working as expected. I'm not getting any update there. Is the code correct?

Comment: Uncomment json_encode($data_string)

Comment: I did that, still it's not working

Comment: welcome to stack overflow, please make sure you visit the [tour] page and the [ask] page. I also highly recommend you read [mcve].

Comment: What does that mean its not working? what is the error?

Comment: Any Errors, Return Values, var dumps for us?

Comment: for one thing, you're not doing anything with `catch (Exception $ex)` you need to echo that `echo "Error: ".$ex->getMessage();`

Comment: try to send this header value as well, I'm sure without this, `cURL` return white/blank page in response to `Ajax` request using `cURL`.
`'X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest'`

Comment: How is the JSON you've given related to the PHP you've given?

Comment: @Popnoodles: yes, but you can post `json` only when you send proper headers alongwith

Comment: where is $url being set? It's not in the example code you posted.

Comment: `json_encode` returns a value. Shouldn't you have `$data_string = json_encode($data_string);`?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
$object = new StdClass;
$object->ActivityEvent = 201;
$object->EmailAddress = 'john.smith@acmeconsulting.co';
//add more properties here
echo json_encode($object);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$datastring = array(
'firstName' => 'John',
'lastName' => 'Smith',
...........);
$ch = curl_init("YOUR_URL_HERE");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $datastring );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

the result will be stored in the `$result` variable